# Is it possible to force multiple paint operations on a 2D canvas (software rendering)?

Tags: google-chrome, canvas, html5-canvas, chromecast

I am working on a game that uses HTML5 canvas 2D context drawing on a Chromecast device (which doesn't have hardware acceleration).  I've noticed that drawing two objects in one frame will trigger a repaint of the entire region that contains both of them.  As a "worst-case", imagine that I want to only change the color of the top-left and bottom-right pixels of a large canvas element.  If I use two one-pixel fillRect calls to do this, it (WebKit/Blink, at least) will mark the entire canvas dirty, triggering a very expensive paint operation.  I believe this should link to the code that performs this logic in Chromium:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/html/HTMLCanvasElement.cpp&l=218

Is there any way to convince the browser to actually perform two small paint operations instead of one (excessively) large one?  Or would this always be slower, despite the fact that it's re-drawing significantly less?  I have tried putting the elements on different canvas elements layered on top of each other, but the browser still seems to catch it and batch them together (at least as shown by the repaint regions in DevTools).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, currently you can't do much better than that; one main drawback is that double buffering is not implemented either, which would have improved the performance. We will be seeing improvements in these areas moving forward.